# How many tasks are created when spark read or write from mysql?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

As far as I know, Spark executors handle many tasks at the same time to guarantee processing data parallelly. Here comes the question. When connecting to external data storage, say mysql, how many tasks are there to finish this job? In other words, are multiple tasks created at the same time and each task reads all data, or data is read from only one task and is distributed to the cluster in some other way? How about writing data to mysql, how many connections are there?

Here is some piece of code to read or write data from/to mysql:

```scala
def jdbc(sqlContext: SQLContext, url: String, driver: String, dbtable: String, user: String, password: String, numPartitions: Int): DataFrame = {
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "url" -> url,
      "driver" -> driver,
      "dbtable" -> s"(SELECT * FROM $dbtable) $dbtable",
      "user" -> user,
      "password" -> password,
      "numPartitions" -> numPartitions.toString
    )).load
}

def mysqlToDF(sparkSession:SparkSession, jdbc:JdbcInfo, table:String): DataFrame ={
    var dF1 = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", jdbc.jdbcUrl)
      .option("user", jdbc.user)
      .option("password", jdbc.passwd)
      .option("driver", jdbc.jdbcDriver)
      .option("dbtable", table)
      .load()
    //    dF1.show(3)
    dF1.createOrReplaceTempView(s"${table}")
    dF1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article which answers your question:
https://freecontent.manning.com/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-with-spark/

In simple words: the workers separate the reading task into several parts and each worker only read a part of your input data. The number of tasks divided depends on your ressources and your data volume. The writing is the same principle: Spark writes the data to a distributed storage system, such as Hdfs and in Hdfs the data is stored in a ditributed way: each worker writes its data to some storage node in Hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

By default data from jdbc source are loaded by one thread so you will have one task processed by one executor and that's the case you may expect in your second function `mysqlToDF`.

In the first function "jdbc" you are closer to parallel read but still some parameters are needed, `numPartitions` is not enough, spark need some integer/date column and lower/upper bounds to be able to read in parallel (it will execute x queries for partial results)

[Spark jdb documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

In this docu you will find:

> **partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound     (none)**    These options must
> all be specified if any of them is specified. In addition,
> numPartitions must be specified. They describe how to partition the
> table when reading in parallel from multiple workers. partitionColumn
> must be a numeric, date, or timestamp column from the table in
> question. Notice that lowerBound and upperBound are just used to
> decide the partition stride, not for filtering the rows in table. So
> all rows in the table will be partitioned and returned. This option
> applies only to reading.

> **numPartitions   (none)**    The maximum
> number of partitions that can be used for parallelism in table reading
> and writing. This also determines the maximum number of concurrent
> JDBC connections. If the number of partitions to write exceeds this
> limit, we decrease it to this limit by calling coalesce(numPartitions)
> before writing.   read/write

regarding write

> How about writing data to mysql,how many connections are there?

As stated in docu it also depends on `numPartitions`, if number of partitions when writing will be higher than `numPartitions` Spark will figure it out and call `coalesce`. Remember that `coalesce` may generate skew so sometimes it may be better to repartition it explicitly with `repartition(numPartitions)` to distribute data equally before write

If you don't set `numPartitions` number of paralell connections on write may be the same as number of active tasks in given moment so be aware that with to high parallelism and no upper bound you may choke source server